# Резиново-фиксированная верстка и bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Как можно сверстать такой сайт, затруднение вызывает что наверху шапка фона слева и справа от центра разная, а центр фиксированный.  И это надо сделать используя bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на телефоне или планшете как должно выглядить? 1000px для телефона все же анриал. Если тетефон не нужен, зачем bootstrap? Еще непонятно - то что 1000px - это типа сверху окно (наложенное поверх фона), или?

Comment: Ширина написана только для примера. Трудность для меня в том что слева один фон, а справа другая картинка, и этот фон должен растягиваться на любых мониторах а в центре шапка которая должна состыковаться с левым и правым фоном.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо что ответили на мой вопрос.
Попробовала ваш код.
Если попробовать уменьшить браузер (влево проверяла как работает при уменьшение экрана) и все колонки выстраиваються  одна под другой. Т.е. вся шапка разьежается.
Упростила задачу сделал фон через градиент (в коде просто однотонный для примера).
Вот написала  свой вариант недостаток почему то длина контейнера text оганичивается текстом а хотелось прижать  footer  к низу. 
 И при движение влево т.е уменьшая браузер правый центр заезжает на мое меню.
Может что подскажите.

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

}
.header-blu{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
min-height: 75px; 
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px; 

}
.header-top{
position: relative;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
min-width: 1px; 

}
.left-top {
 /*  background: url(../images/centr-1.jpg);*/
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
height: auto;
min-height:265px;
}
.right-top{
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
min-height:265px;

}
.header-top-center{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
min-height:1px;
}
.header-center{
position: relative;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
min-height:1px;
 
}
.left-center {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top:0px;
width:300px;
min-height:265px;
}

.right-center {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 300px;
right:0px;
top:0px;
width: 650px ;
min-height:265px;
}

.text{
padding:0px;
margin:235px 0 0 0;
}


.color_pink_light
{
background-color:#F59193;
}
.color_pink{
background-color:#EA5858;
}
.color_blue{
background-color:#4B9FC6;
}
.color_white{
background-color: white;
}
.color_grey{
background-color: #E4E4E4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Document</title>
 
</head>
<body class="color_grey">  
 

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" >
    
   <div class="header-top ">
   <div class="header-blu color_pink_light">
          верхний  фон
   </div>
     <div class="left-top color_blue">left-top</div>
    <div class="right-top color_pink">right-top</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  

 

 <div class="container"  >
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   <div class="header-center">
    <div class="left-center color_blue">
      
    <aside class='col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>not home</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    </div> 
    <div class="right-center color_pink"> 
    Картинка шапка
    </div>
  
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>  
</div>  
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">   
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   <div class="text color_white">
    text <br>
    text <br>
    text <br>
    text <br>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">   
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 color_grey">
   <div class="footer ">
    footer <br>
    footer<br>
    footer<br>
    footer<br>
    footer<br>
 
 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
 
</div> 
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое что хотелось бы отметить, это использование английской грамматики, если вы решили использовать английские слова в вашем вопросле, то стоить проверять правильность их написания. Cлово weight означает вес, а слово width ширину.

Если вернутсья к вашему вопросу, то такой результат можно достичь с помощью Bootstrap'овских классов и нескольких стилей.

Вот мой [**пример**](http://codepen.io/antonk52/pen/MwZPYy)

В нем, я использовал станадртные классы col-md-2 и col-md-10 для того что бы разбить установить ширину менюшки и картинки на одну шестую и 10/12 от всей ширины окна.

Так же использвоал relative позицию для того что бы поднять основной блок на 20px. Ширина этого блока задана в процентах, поэтому если вам важны мобильные устройства, то можно воспользоваться media queries

Разметка

```
<header class="row"></header>
<div class="row">
    <aside class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'>
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>not home</li>
            <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="hero col-md-10 col-sm-10"></div>
</div>
<div class="somestuff">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">My footer</div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Стили

```
header {
  background: #ffc0cb;
  height: 10vh;
}
aside {
  background-color: #dde4eb;
  background: filter-gradient(#dde4eb, #dde4eb, vertical);
  background: background-image(linear-gradient(top, #dde4eb 0%, #dde4eb 1%, #499bea 100%));
  height: 20vh;
  color: #fff;
}
.hero {
  height: 20vh;
  background: url("https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1431730524508-b2f28f2b793a?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1400&q=75&w=1050") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.somestuff {
  background: #cacaca;
  height: 70vh;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Если у меня получилось ответить на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, пометьте данный ответ как верный.